Не работает скрипт в app scripts в google sheets
Сделал скрипт, поставил триггер при редактировании. На тестовой таблице работает, на другой уже нет.
function onEdit(e) {
  var discordUrl = "MYWEBHOOK_URL";

  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  const column1 = sheet.getRange("H:H").getColumn() - 1;
  const column2 = sheet.getRange("I:I").getColumn() - 1;
  const column3 = sheet.getRange("J:J").getColumn() - 1;
  var arrmessage =[];
  for (var i = 3; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][column2] !== "" || data[i][column3] !== "") {
      arrmessage.push({name: `${data[i][column1]}`,value:"",inline: true});
      arrmessage.push({name: `${data[i][column2]}`,value:"",inline: true});
      arrmessage.push({name: `${data[i][column3]}`,value:"",inline: true});
    }
  }
  Logger.log(arrmessage);

  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "payload": JSON.stringify({
      "content": "Бу",
      "embeds": [{
        "color": 16711680,
        "title": "#Лучший стрелок",
        "fields": arrmessage,
        "footer": {
          "text": "TRINITY CLNX"
        }
      }]
    })
  };

  try {
    if (sheetName === "Тарелочки") {
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, options);
    } else {
      Logger.log("Message is empty or contains 'undefined'. No request sent.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error occurred: " + error.toString());
  }
}


Информация   Error occurred: Exception: Вам не разрешено вызывать пользователя UrlFetchApp.fetch. Необходимые разрешения: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request.
Ошибка   TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getSheet')
at onEdit(Код:7:23)


